# Send post request with Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, post, python-requests, http-post

I have this working API in python, How can I re-build the same thing in javascript? if it's not possible, how can I send this POST request from the font-end?

```
import requests

gfg_compiler_api_endpoint = "https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/main.php"
languages = ['C', 'Cpp', 'Cpp14', 'Java', 'Python', 'Python3', 'Scala', 'Php', 'Perl', 'Csharp']


def gfg_compile(lang, code, _input=None, save=False):
    data = {
      'lang': lang,
      'code': code,
      'input': _input,
      'save': save
    }
    r = requests.post(gfg_compiler_api_endpoint, data=data)
    return r.json()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    lang = 'Cpp14'
    code = """
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int man() {
        it a, b;
        cin >> a >> b;
        cout << (a+b);
        return 0;
    }
    """
    _input = "1 5"
    print(gfg_compile(lang, code, _input))
```

Comment: Sorry, SO is not a free code translation service. Look up how to do this in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), try to solve this yourself, and if you're desperately stuck and have exhausted all available resources, come back and edit your question accordingly, include your code and we'll gladly help you fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple **xhr** request.

```
var url = "https://example.com/user";

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", url);

xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
   if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      console.log(xhr.status);
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
   }};

var data = `{
  "Id": 78912,
  "Customer": "Jason Sweet",
  "Quantity": 1,
  "Price": 18.00
}`;

xhr.send(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'axios' library. For example,

```
axios.post('https:localhost:300/page', {
    var1: 'abcd',
    var2: '1234'
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
```

You may look up their documentation, https://axios-http.com/.
There are tons of youtube videos where it is explained thoroughly.